# Rendering SVG ARC in AFP (advanced function presentation) using Apache FOP

Tags: svg, apache-fop, apache-xml-graphics

I am using  apache fop xmlgraphics 2.2 to generate SVG for PDF and AFP, Bellow is the code snippet which I have coded

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object><svg:svg width="5.4928cm" height="5.4928cm" viewBox="0 0 400 400"><svg:path stroke="#70237B" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#C1BDBC" d="M 200,200 L 200,0 A200,200 0 1,1 143.87,391.96 z"/></svg:svg></fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

Which renders properly in the PDF, However the same code snippet doesn’t work for AFP. Code generates the ARC shape but doesn’t fill the color(attribute fill="#C1BDBC" doesn’t work in case of AFP).
The Above mentioned  problem happens only when rendering Arc’s for AFP, Other Shapes  like circle, polygon works fine.

Please let me know if I have to do anything  Which is specific to AFP.

attached the svg's generated for reference.

[AFP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoljU.png)
[PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4y0x.png)

Comment: The SVG in your XML doesn't look much like the image in your PDF screenshot.  Have you included all of it? https://jsfiddle.net/z489nv8p/2/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I have added only one ARC path in the code snippet and what you see it the jsfiddle is correct,which is working fine when i render HTML or PDF,But Same code snippet doesn't fill the color in case of  AFP.